# Почему в мониторе ресурсов Windows у Цп 105% максимальной частоты?

Tags: windows, железо, процессор

В мониторе ресурсов от Windows в разделе ЦП пишет что у меня 105 иногда 106% максимальной частоты, почему так?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно включён турбо буст процессора в биосе, либо процессор разогнан (менее вероятно)

Comment: @MoloF, скорее всего, именно турбо буст. В Windows 8 на интелах - частое событие